# Problem with filezilla disconecting

Tags: 14.04, sftp, filezilla, disconnect

I've install FileZilla on my computer who use Ubuntu as operating system and I have a problem. After I connect and display `Directory listing of "/" successful`, everityme I try to download or access a folder is keep disconnecting without printing an error.
Connection type is sftp.
Any ideas why?

Comment: does it work from command line? Do you see some errors in server log?

Comment: It seems that I haved a problem with it when install it from comand line. I get folder from their site and install it in thet way and it works.